# Mount an additional Xserve volume with autofs on Linux

Tags: linux, mac-osx-server, xserve, autofs

A few years ago I setup **autofs** on a **RH Linux** box to mount volumes from four XServes. I need to add a couple new volumes from these same Xserves so that I can access files from the Linux box. I've completely forgotten how to do this and haven't been able to find a solution online. How do I add the new volumes? Do I need to add paths to the new volumes?

Answer (score 0):

The XServe needs to be setup - Protocols/NFS Export Settings - check *Export this item and its contents to*, added the Linux box's IP and setup the pull-down to Client.

On the linux box- nothing need be setup. autofs will now work with the new volumes just as it does the previously set-up volumes.

Now I can access the XServes from the Linux box like:

```
/net/xserve_id_address_here/Volumes/Mount/folder
```

or

```
/net/100.100.100.100/Volumes/MyMount/MyData
```